# Unable to get data from java web service

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, web-services, batch-file

Someone please help me i keep trying but not able to find out why i am unable to get the results.

I have created this java springboot web service where when I run the java application, a web browser page will open and when I type in the URL e.g `localhost:8080/runbatchfileparam/test.bat` the program will check if the test.bat file exist first. If it does, the web page will show a JSON result `{“Result”: true}` and the command in the batch file will be executed. If it  does not exist, the web page will show `{“Result”: false}`.

I want to create an ASP.NET Web Service that will use the function created in the java web service. When I run the ASP.NET Web Application, a web browser page will open. User will type in URL something like this: `localhost:12345/api/callbatchfile/test.bat`. The java web service should be running and I should get either `{“Result”: true}` or `{“Result”: false}` when I run the C# ASP.NET Web Application too.

However I only get an empty {} without anything inside the brackets. Why is that so?

Here are my code in ASP.NET

**TestController.cs**

```
private TestClient testClient = new TestClient();
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GET(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await testClient.runbatchfile(fileName);
            var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestVariable>(result);
            return Json(resultDTO);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var result = "Server is not running";
            return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result });
        }
    }
```

**TestVariable.cs**

```
public class TestVariable
{
    public static int fileName { get; set; }       
}
```

**TestClient.cs**

```
private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static TestClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> runbatchfile(string fileName)
    {
        var endpoint = string.Format("runbatchfile/{0}", fileName);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TestBatchClient",
            routeTemplate: "api/runbatchfile/{fileName}",
            defaults: new { action = "GET", controller = "Test" }
        );
```

Someone please do help me. Thank you so much.

**EDIT**

**Java web service**

**Application.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

**BatchFileController.java**

```
private static final String template = "Sum, %s!";  

@RequestMapping("/runbatchfile/{param:.+}")
public ResultFormat runbatchFile(@PathVariable("param") String fileName) {
RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
return rbf.runBatch(fileName);
}
```

**ResultFormat**

```
private boolean result;

public ResultFormat(boolean result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public boolean getResult() {
    return result;
}
```

**RunBatchFile.java**

```
public ResultFormat runBatch(String fileName) {

    String var = fileName;
    String filePath = ("C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/" + var);
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        return new ResultFormat(exitVal == 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResultFormat(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the web service code look like?

Comment: Hi i have added the codes in.

Comment: If you do not get any result other than `{}` when you access the page in a web browser the problem is most likely on the server side. Not entirely sure how the flow goes, but when you open the url it is accessing the server directly, right?

Comment: When i run the java web service URL: `http://localhost:8080/runbatchfileparam/test.bat` i get the proper result but when i run the ASP.NET application i do not get the result. And yes, directly accessing the server.

Comment: .net app calling `var endpoint = string.Format("runbatchFile/{0}", FileName);` but service definition is @RequestMapping("/runbatchfileparam/{param:.+}")

Comment: change endpoint to `string.Format("runbatchfileparam/{0}", FileName);`

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. I changed that however i still get empty `{}`

Comment: I think the problem is with the endpoint. What should i change that to?

Comment: what the content type of the response is when it tests with postman?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps.. but I suspect that the AsyncTask is not really executing...

```
var result = await testClient.testCallBatchProject(fileName);
```

I would try something like below:

```
await testClient.testCallBatchProject(fileName).Delay(1000);
```

Can you try and check if the same happens for a synchronous call? .. if it does, we can zero down on the above.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. However when i try that, the whole line of code gives error `Member Task.Delay(int) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Comment: Did you try making a synchronous call for the same HTTP request?

Comment: I followed a tutorial to do this i am unsure on how to change the whole thing to synchronous call. Anyway i used the exact same method to call a java web service with integer parameters and it worked fine. The only difference is now i am using `string fileName` and it is not working